# Converting WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to new 5.7.0 syntax using InMemoryUserDetailsManager, getting No AuthenticationProvider found

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to update an application to Spring Boot 2.7, which brings Spring Security to 5.7 and deprecates `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Here's a simplified version of the old code, that creates a single user, and works. Note that this code is used only for local development and testing, using a simple form login:

```java
@Configuration
@Profile("local-auth")
class LocalAuth {
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter webSecurityConfigurerAdapter(
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        return new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                        .withUser("testuser")
                        .password(passwordEncoder.encode("a"))
                        .authorities(toAuthorities(List.of("SOME_AUTHORITY")));
            }

            private List<? extends GrantedAuthority> toAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
                return roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                        .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                                authorizeRequests
                                        .antMatchers("/login", "/actuator/**", "/publico/**").permitAll()
                                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        )
                        .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:4200/app/").permitAll())
                        .logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/logout"))
                        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Following the guide at https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter, I changed the code to

```java
@Configuration
@Profile("local-auth")
class LocalAuth {
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("testuser")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("a"))
                .authorities(toAuthorities(List.of("SOME_AUTHORITY")))
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    private List<? extends GrantedAuthority> toAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .antMatchers("/login", "/actuator/**", "/publico/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:4200/app/").permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/logout"))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

The login form is displayed, but when I try to login, I get this error in the login page:
**No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken**. Strangely, nothing gets printed in the application log.

I've also tried to provide an `AuthenticationManager` replacing the first bean with

```java
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) throws Exception {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("govbr.20821922459")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("a"))
                .authorities(toAuthorities(List.of("LU_NVL_CONTA_BASICA")))
                .build();
        return authBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(user).and().build();
    }
```

but then the application fails to start with
**Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@313c3cb to already built object**.

Does anyone know the proper way to convert the old `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

**Edit**: Even increasing log level to DEBUG, all I get in a login attempt is

```
2022-07-27 14:22:26.012 [                    ] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy             - Securing POST /login
2022-07-27 14:22:26.013 [                    ] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter    - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-07-27 14:22:26.015 [                    ] DEBUG o.s.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy      - Redirecting to /svr/rest/login?error
2022-07-27 14:22:26.015 [                    ] DEBUG .s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-07-27 14:22:26.015 [                    ] DEBUG .s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-07-27 14:22:26.015 [                    ] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter    - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-07-27 14:22:26.041 [                    ] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy             - Securing GET /login?error
2022-07-27 14:22:26.041 [                    ] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter    - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-07-27 14:22:26.042 [                    ] DEBUG .s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-07-27 14:22:26.042 [                    ] DEBUG .s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-07-27 14:22:26.042 [                    ] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter    - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

and the respose to the POST to `/login` is a 302 redirect to `/login?error`, with no reference to any specific error message or code (unless the error message is determined from the session).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: the code for authentication in production was creating a `UserDetailsService` bean as well, so that there were two in the ApplicationContext. This must disable the Spring auto-configuration code that creates whatever is necessary for the in-memory authentication to work.

The solution was to disable the production bean when the local profile is selected. And it seems that's the only possible solution: neither adding `@Primary` nor adding `@Order` with a higher priority than the prodution bean worked.

**Edit**: Indeed, configuration is done by the `InitializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer` class, and it checks that there is only one bean of type `UserDetailsService` (it's even documented in its Javadoc).

---

Another possibility is to create an `AuthenticationProvider` manually, pointing to the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager`. To do that, just register a `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` bean (this is a general way to configure the `AuthenticationManager` as it is being built):

```java
@Bean
GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter adapter(InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetails, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    return new GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            provider.setUserDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetails);
            provider.setUserDetailsPasswordService(inMemoryUserDetails);
            provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
            auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues getting a handle to the authentication manager in non-WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configurations unless I use the apply() with dsl.  But I think you can get this to work without the auth manager. Warning: this example does not use a password encoder which you should definitely use in any production environment.

```java
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                                .username("admin")
                                .password("{noop}" + "password")
                               .roles("ADMIN")
                               .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);

        return provider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider(userDetailsService()));
        
        return http.build();    
    }
```